# Construct a pair of mirrored cells in two different worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a pair of cells on two different sheets of my workbook, such that anything you enter into one cell gets copied across to the other. If this was one way, it would obviously be trivial. I want to make it so that the link is two-way, though. That's going to involve VBA scripting, and I'm something of a novice at that. Does anyone have some pointers on how to learn what I need to know? I have Googled, but that just produced some code samples without explanation, and I don't want to put in code that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have Sheet1 and Sheet2 and their names are exactly that.

1. At Sheet1, go to Developer and click on View Code. You should be looking at a blank coding sheet for Sheet1
2. On the left drop down of the coding area, select Worksheet instead of the default (General)
3. On the right drop down. select Change. You would automatically be given the following:

> ```
> Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
>
> End Sub
> ```

Changes to any cell in Sheet1 will trigger the code above.

The cell that has been changed is referred to as the Target range.

You can easily identify the address and content of the Target range using Target.Address and Target.Value. You can then use this address and value to update Sheet2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

To copy data from Sheet2 to Sheet1, just repeat the steps above but at Sheet2.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value

End Sub
```

However, if change to Sheet1 will trigger a change to Sheet2, which in turn will trigger a change to Sheet1, the changes will happen for an indefinite time which does not make sense. Therefore, we need to add some code to apply the change only when the values on both Sheet1 and Sheet2 are different. If the values are the same, there is no need to apply change. Therefore, the code for Sheet2 should appear as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Address).Value <> Target.Value Then

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value

     End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your solution is valid, and it's good enough for the simple case we've got here. As a matter of personal preference, I'd identify the paired ranges and ensure *only* the relevant range triggers the change by putting in a guard clause like "If Not Target Is myRange Then Exit Sub".    Looking at more complex cases, an event procedure that performs an action which can trigger subsequent events is always worrying: I'd start the code with Application.EnableEvents=False and exit with Application.EnableEvents=True ...You *still* need "If Application.EnableEvents Then Exit Sub".

Answer (score 0):

You would use a pair of **event macros** to accomplish this.  Here is an example that you can adapt:

[mirror changes](https://superuser.com/questions/835301/mirror-cells-so-that-a-change-in-either-cell-updates-the-other/835422#835422)